# Jquery Ajax not working while using json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get value from `Jquery Ajax`, but it is not getting.

The problem is in the below code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_GET['od'])){
    $deotd = $_GET['od'];
}
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$cdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', time());
$scdate = strtotime($cdate);
$e = $scdate - $deotd;
$f = "2700" - $e;

// You would calculate a real value here
echo json_encode([
  'tleft' => $f
]),
json_encode([
  'diffex' => $e
]);
?>
```

In deep the problem is with:

```
echo json_encode([
  'tleft' => $f
]),
json_encode([
  'diffex' => $e
]);
```

But what is the problem, I am unable to solve it.

Comment: Where's your ajax?

Comment: `echo json_encode(['tleft' => $f]), json_encode([  'diffex' => $e]);` You're calling `json_encode` twice, and the second time as a second argument of the first. You should combine them into one array and call `json_encode` only once

Comment: try to echo only one json  you can have both keys and values in there

Comment: @johnSmith How?

Comment: @Machavity How?

Comment: @MKJ `echo json_encode([
  'tleft' => $f, 'diffex' => $e
]);`

Comment: @MKJ You really need to read the manual on this one. This is a fundamental of how PHP works http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Machavity Dont think its a duplicate, the question is just not asked good. Think He/She wants to parse the data on the javascript side

Comment: @johnSmith Yeah, I picked the wrong one. I finally chased down the proper dupe and fixed it